# Autodesk Vault API - upload version files to a selected folder for selected files

Tags: c

I'm working with Autodesk Vault. I need to upload files of all versions to the selected folder for the selected files. I have a path that I get from the directory tree. I don’t fully understand how to download version files on a given path to a folder.

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/vault-customization/how-to-get-previous-and-next-version-of-file-using-vault/td-p/6774315

```
 void HelloWorldCommandHandler(object s, CommandItemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                VDF.Vault.Currency.Connections.Connection connection = e.Context.Application.Connection;

            if (e.Context.CurrentSelectionSet.Count() == 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing is selected");
            else
            {
                // we only have one item selected, which is the expected behavior
                ISelection selection = e.Context.CurrentSelectionSet.First();

                // Look of the File object.  How we do this depends on what is selected.
                File[] selectedFile = null;
                if (selection.TypeId == SelectionTypeId.File)
                {
                    selectedFile = connection.WebServiceManager.DocumentService.GetFilesByMasterId(selection.Id);
                }

                if (selectedFile == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Selection is not a file.");
                }
                else
                {
                    FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
                    dialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;
                    dialog.Description = "Please select a folder to insert back-up files";
                    dialog.ShowNewFolderButton = false;

                    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        //System.IO.DirectoryInfo destin = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"dialog.SelectedPath");
                        //???????

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // If something goes wrong, we don't want the exception to bubble up to Vault Explorer.
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This isn't [tag:c]. I'd assume [tag:c++], maybe [tag:c#].

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you have to list versions Id's by Master Id of the file.

You have 2 methods:
If you have numbered versions of the file then:

```
GetFileByVersion(long FileID, int FileVersion)
```

or get files object:

```
GetFilesByMasterID(long MasterID)
```

Indeed you do not get `File` with this method. Only `File` object.
To Download file you should use acquire vault method.

BTW mark question as c#.